# HTTP video player in Omnet?

Tags: video, stream, omnet++

I am new to Omnet++ and want to simulate HTTP video player at the client end which streams videos from a server. Does anybody knows about some library that could be used

Comment: this could be the closest thing to what you want: https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/tree/master/examples/inet/nclients , from the `inet` framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out the INET Framework, which has models for video simulation. Quoting the documentation:

> The UDPVideoStreamCli and UDPVideoStreamSvr modules in the inet.applications.udp package provide a simple video streaming model; video traffic is modeled as CBR stream.

When you start the OMNeT++ IDE for the first time, it will ask you whether it should download that -- alternatively you can download it from the website. You can find an overview of all models (and the associated packages, in case you forgot to install them with OMNeT++) in that framework here:
https://inet.omnetpp.org/Protocols.html

According to that list, there should also be a detailed trace-based list in a component in the OMNeT++ download area, although the link provided doesn't seem to work any more.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks, @Cleb! The link was intended as additional information -- I added some details to the answer that may be useful. In case that link ever stops working, readers should look at the INET Framework documentation directly.